# Find an optimal route between multiple map locations

Tags: google-maps, bing-maps

For me the ideal app would push the route to Google maps so I could save it to My Maps and use Google Navigation in the car to travel the route.  *Any* solution would be good though.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to accomplish:
We're in a completely new city/state, don't know the area, looking to buy a new home.  Before we ride around with an agent we'd like to drive around to say 10-15 houses and check out the neighborhoods so we can focus our initial search with the agent.

Ideally I could plug 15 addresses into Google Maps and it would optimize the route.  (FYI, this is the "[traveling salesman problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem)").  However, Google doesn't attempt to optimize the route and just takes the order you feed it.

Comment: With the ability to drag & drop destinations on the left hand panel, you could probably quickly optimize the route yourself. Unfortunately though, Google doesn't figure this out automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found one!  This is simple and actually does exactly what I'm looking for.

It is called [Find the Best Route](http://findthebestroute.com/RouteFinder.html)

1. Enter addresses.
2. Optimize route.
3. Export to Google Maps.

The limit is 24 addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding multiple destinations

Here is a trip from [Houston to Atlanta to Las Vegas](http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&source=s_d&saddr=Houston,%20TX&daddr=Atlanta,%20GA%20to:Las%20Vegas,%20NV&hl=en&geocode=FUQlxgEd6pFQ-ikBhY1ItLhAhjE7BWXz3gINyg;FQP4AgIdclf4-imNCZNpXQT1iDELYwuZL97-Zg;FdYQJwIdMJoi-SnRffWkgre-gDGjebPV5tXMOg&mra=ls&sll=32.94059,-99.78133&sspn=20.584844,39.506836&ie=UTF8&z=5).

Then click save to [My Maps](http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?doflg=ptm&ie=UTF8&msa=0&msid=201050091785607416268.0004a48120fe085e810d1&ll=32.93836,-99.78395&spn=20.584844,39.506836&z=5).

[image]

Comment: Yes, thanks.  This is more for the purpose of hunting for a new house. Updating question now...